# Editing Stack Overflow questions with minimal impact... why?

Tags: discussion, edits

Does this give the editor reputation points? Perhaps it should be looked what the edits actually are... check out this 'edit' one of my posts from @Leonardo... Can someone tell me the additional benefit of these edits?

[image]

Comment: It looks like an attempt to make your post easier to read. Is that benefit not enough?

Comment: That user does not receive reputation from edits. You should be grateful that there are people who are editing it to make it better, even when it's only a tiny improvement.

Comment: What is wrong with this edit?

Comment: Have you read the [help center](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing) or the [FAQ](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/120576/289905) or the other [FAQ](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788/289905) or the [tag wiki of the “edits” tag](/tags/edits/info) which you should have included? Speaking of which, have you read [How to Ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which says _“Include all relevant tags”_ and _“be sure and read the descriptions given for them to make sure they’re relevant to the question you’re asking”_ and links to [the tagging help](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)?

Comment: You must be viewing Stack Overflow on quite a wide screen; for most readers, your single very long line of code would not fit horizontally so the edit saves people from having to scroll horizontally to see all of the code. It also fixes your indentation and formatting. What about the edit do you object to?

Answer (score -2):

The edit seems fine to me.

First of all, 2k users earn a privilege that makes them can edit questions and answer, so if we edit something, we don't gain reputation from it.

Second, this edit is good, because it fixed code formatting.

Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){int a, int b; std::cin >> a >> b; std::cout << a << b;}
```

with this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a, 
    int b; 
    std::cin >> a >> b; 
    std::cout << a << b;
}
```

You can see with a little bit of formatting, we can easily identify the problem. And it also looks pleasing to the eyes.

Comment: Editing privileges start long before 2K. That is the threshold that edits don't require additional approvals

Comment: Yes, but the edit summary should make the *intent* clear and perhaps draw attention to the more appropriate "Side-by-side Markdown" view for this kind of formatting change  ("deleted 175 characters in body" is not sufficient).

Comment: I agree that in the edit on my post the 'df <- .... ' has improved readability by restructuring it! The rest though.... Good to hear no credits are earned

Comment: @Luc why do you think that getting reputation in this case is bad?

Comment: @justANewbie I think getting reputation for improvements is a really good thing, as long as the changes are useful... After I posted this, various people went to edit ALL my posts (yeah, saw that coming...), and most of the edits (in my mind) have not increased clarity at all.